# Can I put a well known alias of mine in place of my legal name in the space where one lists the Copyright Holders?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I made some code of mine publicly available under the MIT License. ([See the actual copy of the license file here](https://github.com/theManikJindal/httpserver/blob/master/LICENSE.md))

The license as per norms starts with the lines

```
The MIT License (MIT) 
Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>
```

In the license file attached with my code, I have used a well known alias of mine. *By well known, I mean that all my public profiles on the internet use this alias.*

But this is not my legal name.

- Is it not advisable to do so, in context of copyright laws?
- Do you see me running into any legal troubles claiming violation of copyright because I used an alias?
- If I did want to use my alias, what steps would you suggest I undertake, so as to not run into trouble if I wish to claim copyright in the future.

Comment: Related: [How to express copyright when you use a pen name](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/10910/10).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use your real name. See [this document](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428165628/https://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl101.pdf), pertaining to pseudonyms and copyright (there may be different requirements [in India](https://copyright.gov.in/UserRegistration/frmLoginPage.aspx)). If you register the copyright (in the US a prerequisite for an infringement lawsuit), leave the author name blank, but you can use the pseudonym for the copyright claimant. The main problem would be establishing identity, i.e. establishing that you are *that* theManikJindal – the photo helps.